# Obtain count of unique combination of columns in R dataframe without eliminating the duplicate columns from the data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data :

```
   A    B   C   D     E 
 1 130 288   6   80    57299 
 2 288 130   6   57299 80 
 3 288 130   6   57299 80 
 4 288 130   6   57299 80 
 5 288 130   6   57299 80 
 6 288 130   6   57299 80 
 7 288 130   6   57299 80  
 8 288 130   6   57299 80   
 9 288 130   6   57299 80 
10 130 288   6   80    57299
```

I want to obtain count of unique combination of these columns and append a Frequency column to the existing dataframe without eliminating the duplicate rows. Following is what I want

```
   A    B   C    D     E      Freq
 1 130 288   6   80    57299  2
 2 288 130   6   57299 80     8
 3 288 130   6   57299 80     8
 4 288 130   6   57299 80     8
 5 288 130   6   57299 80     8
 6 288 130   6   57299 80     8
 7 288 130   6   57299 80     8
 8 288 130   6   57299 80     8
 9 288 130   6   57299 80     8
10 130 288   6   80    57299  2
```

Trying `df_0 <- count(df, A,B,C,D,E) %>% ungroup()` gives me

```
    A    B   C    D     E      Freq
 1 130 288   6   80    57299  2
 2 288 130   6   57299 80     8
```

By eliminating the duplicates.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Python tag? Why?

Comment: Was trying in Python as well, removed the tag since I do not have the corresponding code in python. Thanks

Comment: So , you need python this time too ?LOL, I will add python solution .

Comment: Thanks Wen, R is good. However if you have python solution handy, would love to learn from your share.

Comment: @Sneha added~ python solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R `dplyr` `mutate`

```
dat%>%group_by_(.dots=names(dat))%>%dplyr::mutate(Freq=n())
```

Python `transform`

```
df['Freq']=df.groupby(list(df))['A'].transform('count')
```

Comment: I don't know R but this seems fancy. +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you ~

Comment: @Sneha,   as the question you asked before add both R and python solution

Comment: @Wen - Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want `add_count`:

```
df_0 <- add_count(df, A,B,C,D,E)
```

From the help page for `?count`:

> `add_tally()` adds a column "n" to a table based on the number of items within each existing group, while `add_count()` is a shortcut that does the grouping as well. These functions are to `tally()` and `count()` as `mutate()` is to `summarise()`: they add an additional column rather than collapsing each group.

Comment: Both the solutions worked perfect. Thanks Wen and Gregor. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer.